# Is there a way to get the output of a function in a vector or list in R?

Tags: r, function, output

I'm running a function that runs a neural network for n layers, and the output makes sense, but I can't seem to get the output as an object that I can then work with and plot a fitting graph for. Any help would be greatly appreciated. My code is as follows:

```
#Loading the library and setting the seed
library(nnet)
set.seed(123)

#Function for n depth in a neural network predicting the sale of a listing
NN_layers <- function(n){
  for(n in 1:20){
#Defining the data
listings_NN <- head(listings, 10000)
#Setting the first 70% of observations as training set and the last 30% as test data
pctTrain <- 0.7
numTrain <- round(pctTrain*nrow(listings_NN))
obsTrain <- sample(1:nrow(listings_NN), numTrain)

listings_NN_train <- listings_NN[obsTrain,]
listings_NN_test  <- listings_NN[-obsTrain,]

#Defining the model
mdlNN <- sold ~ agent_present + region_index + type_index + area + bedrooms + bathrooms + floor + parking_spot + construction_decade + living_rooms + kitchens + has_fireplace + plot_area + balconies_area + orientation_index + price

#Executing the model
rsltNN <- nnet(mdlNN, data=listings_NN_train, size = 5, maxit = 300, trace = FALSE, MaxNWts = 2715)
predNN_train <- predict(rsltNN, listings_NN_train, type = "class")
predNN_test <- predict(rsltNN, listings_NN_test, type = "class")
accuracy_train <- mean(listings_NN_train$sold == predNN_train)
accuracy_test <- mean(listings_NN_test$sold == predNN_test)
v.list <- print(c(accuracy_train, accuracy_test))
}}

#Function output gives a list of 20 observations for both the training set and the test set.
NN_layers()
```

The function does output values that make sense, but how do I get them into an object I can work with? The output I get is the following, where each row is an iteration with the accuracy for the training set and the test set.

```
[1] 0.6950000 0.6983333
[1] 0.6968571 0.6940000
[1] 0.6992857 0.6883333
[1] 0.6935714 0.7016667
[1] 0.6952857 0.6980000
[1] 0.6942857 0.7000000
[1] 0.6937143 0.7013333
[1] 0.6962857 0.6953333
[1] 0.6962857 0.6956667
[1] 0.6982857 0.6906667
[1] 0.6941429 0.7006667
[1] 0.7032857 0.6793333
[1] 0.7017143 0.6826667
[1] 0.6967143 0.6946667
[1] 0.6941429 0.7006667
[1] 0.6972857 0.6930000
[1] 0.6978571 0.6920000
[1] 0.6967143 0.6946667
[1] 0.699 0.689
[1] 0.6958571 0.6963333
```

I've tried assigning the function to an object, but the object type is 'NULL' and it seems to be empty. What am I missing?

Comment: R functions return their last line by default. Since your final statement is `print`, nothing is returned. Try `v.list <- c(accuracy_train, accuracy_test)`

Comment: This is not accurate, `print()` returns its input, so `v.list <- c(accuracy_train, accuracy_test)` and `v.list <- print(c(accuracy_train, accuracy_test))` return the same, namely `c(accuracy_train, accuracy_test)`. They return it invisibly though because the last call of the function is an assignment. To answer the question we'll probably need to be able to reproduce it , which we can't because `listings` object is not found.